# Error while running selendroid in linux

Tags: java, android-sdk-2.3, selendroid

I am using android sdk bundle 64bit for linux os

Here is my java version: -

```
java version "1.6.0_24"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.1) (6b24-1.11.1-4ubuntu3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
```

Running the following command,

```
java -jar selendroid-standalone-0.10.0-with-dependencies.jar
```

Getting the following error,

```
SEVERE: Error occurred while building server: io.selendroid.exceptions.ShellCommandException: An error occured while executing shell command: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/jarsigner -sigalg MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -signedjar /tmp/resigned-android-driver1919587484776084261.apk -storepass android -keystore /home/test/.android/debug.keystore /tmp/android-driver1919587484776084261.apk androiddebugkey
java.lang.RuntimeException: io.selendroid.exceptions.ShellCommandException: An error occured while executing shell command: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/jarsigner -sigalg MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -signedjar /tmp/resigned-android-driver1919587484776084261.apk -storepass android -keystore /home/test/.android/debug.keystore /tmp/android-driver1919587484776084261.apk androiddebugkey
    at io.selendroid.server.model.SelendroidStandaloneDriver.initApplicationsUnderTest(SelendroidStandaloneDriver.java:142)
    at io.selendroid.server.model.SelendroidStandaloneDriver.<init>(SelendroidStandaloneDriver.java:80)
    at io.selendroid.server.SelendroidStandaloneServer.initializeSelendroidServer(SelendroidStandaloneServer.java:91)
    at io.selendroid.server.SelendroidStandaloneServer.<init>(SelendroidStandaloneServer.java:65)
    at io.selendroid.SelendroidLauncher.launchServer(SelendroidLauncher.java:49)
    at io.selendroid.SelendroidLauncher.main(SelendroidLauncher.java:105)
Caused by: io.selendroid.exceptions.ShellCommandException: An error occured while executing shell command: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/jarsigner -sigalg MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -signedjar /tmp/resigned-android-driver1919587484776084261.apk -storepass android -keystore /home/test/.android/debug.keystore /tmp/android-driver1919587484776084261.apk androiddebugkey
    at io.selendroid.io.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:49)
    at io.selendroid.builder.SelendroidServerBuilder.signTestServer(SelendroidServerBuilder.java:274)
    at io.selendroid.builder.SelendroidServerBuilder.resignApp(SelendroidServerBuilder.java:134)
    at io.selendroid.server.model.SelendroidStandaloneDriver.initApplicationsUnderTest(SelendroidStandaloneDriver.java:138)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: io.selendroid.exceptions.ShellCommandException: 
    ... 9 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: io.selendroid.exceptions.ShellCommandException: An error occured while executing shell command: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/jarsigner -sigalg MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -signedjar /tmp/resigned-android-driver1919587484776084261.apk -storepass android -keystore /home/test/.android/debug.keystore /tmp/android-driver1919587484776084261.apk androiddebugkey
    at io.selendroid.server.model.SelendroidStandaloneDriver.initApplicationsUnderTest(SelendroidStandaloneDriver.java:142)
    at io.selendroid.server.model.SelendroidStandaloneDriver.<init>(SelendroidStandaloneDriver.java:80)
    at io.selendroid.server.SelendroidStandaloneServer.initializeSelendroidServer(SelendroidStandaloneServer.java:91)
    at io.selendroid.server.SelendroidStandaloneServer.<init>(SelendroidStandaloneServer.java:65)
    at io.selendroid.SelendroidLauncher.launchServer(SelendroidLauncher.java:49)
    at io.selendroid.SelendroidLauncher.main(SelendroidLauncher.java:105)
Caused by: io.selendroid.exceptions.ShellCommandException: An error occured while executing shell command: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/jarsigner -sigalg MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -signedjar /tmp/resigned-android-driver1919587484776084261.apk -storepass android -keystore /home/test/.android/debug.keystore /tmp/android-driver1919587484776084261.apk androiddebugkey
    at io.selendroid.io.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:49)
    at io.selendroid.builder.SelendroidServerBuilder.signTestServer(SelendroidServerBuilder.java:274)
    at io.selendroid.builder.SelendroidServerBuilder.resignApp(SelendroidServerBuilder.java:134)
    at io.selendroid.server.model.SelendroidStandaloneDriver.initApplicationsUnderTest(SelendroidStandaloneDriver.java:138)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: io.selendroid.exceptions.ShellCommandException: 
    ... 9 more
```

How do i resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have set the Java path in .bashrc file in linux. Then this error is resolved for me.

Here are the lines in .bashrc file

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```